# i am not able to monitor the spring application through javamelody

Tags: java, spring, java-melody

I am not able to monitor spring application through `java-melody`.
Can some one help me on `java-melody` with spring configuration?
when I pass the URL of spring application in `java-melody` then I should be able to see the monitoring window.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is maven managed then just add javamelody dependency to you pom

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
    <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.55.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

If its not maven managed, then you can simply download and copy javamelody.jar and jrobin-x.jar to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Once you have this, make sure you've defined java meleody filters in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Above should give you basic monitoring at `http://<host>:<port>/<context_root>/monitoring`

For batch and business facaded you can follow the links as posted by @Pantelis. If you want to monitor SQLs executed, you can follow this link on the User guide - https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#7._JDBC

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

JavaMelody user guide: https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide

Basic configuration steps that you need:

1. Add javamelody.jar and jrobin-x.jar in your classpath
2. Add in your web.xml the monitoring filter and session listener as defined there: https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#2._web.xml_file
3. You can define the business facades (eg service layer) in the Spring application context: [https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#9._Business_facades_(if_Spring)](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#9._Business_facades_%28if_Spring%29)
4. You can also configure any batch jobs in the Spring application context: [https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#13._Batch_jobs_(if_Quartz)](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#13._Batch_jobs_%28if_Quartz%29)

With steps 1 and 2 you will have a very basic performance report. I suggest that you read the user guide first.